# Cleaner way to use jq selection

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, jq

The background of my question is loaded; but I'd like to focus on just the `jq` portion in this current piece (although if you could help in its entirety, it'd be so very much welcomed and appreciated).

I have a Terraform spec that I've successfully applied to create an autoscaling group in AWS (re: Terraform provisioning I will ask on a separate question, if perhaps there's a better way than what I'm doing). I had wanted to run some provisioning in each of the produced instances, and in so doing, I decided to couple it with an `ansible` command.

Ansible, as you may know, runs on inventory/host file. Consequently, I'd have to update my host file each time AWS scales up or down in order to successfully run the following ansible ad-hoc command `ansible -i ./myansible.hostfile myawsinstances -a "reprovisioning_command"` (which itself has a different set of issues, tbd.)

On the part of creating the ansible host file, I got what I needed using the following command:

**command sample 1**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq .Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{print "inst"$1 " ansible_ssh_host="$1 " ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu"}' > myansible.hostfile
```

**output sample 1 in `myansible.hostfile`**

```
inst[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
inst[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

It seems to me rather long and somewhat convoluted.

If I were to just use `jq` alone along with its string operation facilities, such as:

**command sample 2**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '"inst" + .Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress + " ansible_ssh_hosts=" + .Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress + " ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu"' > myansible.hostfile
```

I would receive dupes of the output like so:

**output sample 2 in `myansible.hostfile`**

```
inst[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
inst[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
inst[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no1] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
inst[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_host=[ip_no2] ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

Presumably because I'm calling the object selectors twice in the same command.
The question is:

a. **Is there a cleaner command expression that I could use instead of (command sample 1) to achieve the same (output sample 1)?**

b. **What would be the correct way to strictly use `jq` command like in (command sample 2) in order to produce the desired (output sample 1) without dupes like in the (output sample 2)?**

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, jq's `-r` option will remove the outermost quotation marks from JSON string outputs.

Second, the following jq filter, used in conjunction with the aforementioned `-r` option, should be sufficient to achieve your goals, though it's hard to verify since you haven't provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress
| "inst" + . + " ansible_ssh_hosts=" + . + " ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu"
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you again for your answer. That's what I was looking for. Specifically re: MCVE, I couldn't explicitly do so necessarily since it's based on an AWS instance existence. So I asked it in an as generic as possible, leaving the streaming input the response of something else. But the "|" and "." were essentially the answers I sought. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're setting an Ansible inventory name that includes the IP address as this seems pretty pointless to me as it doesn't give it a human readable name or add anything useful compared to just using the IP address.

If you're happy with ditching that requirement then in reality you can just use the [`query` option of the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter) and ditch `jq` and your formatting:

```
cat <<EOF > hosts-file.ini
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

[all]
EOF
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text >> hosts-file.ini
```

This will set some inline vars at the all level to set the SSH user to be `ubuntu` and then dump all of the EC2 instance's public IP addresses under the `all` block.

Comment: Hello, I accepted @peak's answer because it specifically addressed my question. But your answer is also great! To your question, I wanted to keep the ansible host file of going with sequential inst1..n. I haven't really fully decided the end game configurations for the sys, so I figured... ok I'll just use the IPs for now and figure out the next step later. So in general I'm thinking of dropping multiple groups inside the host file, some with different ssh users for different groups.I noticed from your profile that you're an infrastructure engr. What's the recomm. best practice?

Comment: Best practice is to use Ansible to configure an image and then deploy that instead of trying to run Ansible against a moving target. I use Packer with Ansible for AMI creation (currently all in on AWS) and then Terraform to deploy those images in autoscaling groups. If I want to update something I create a new image and Terraform picks up the new AMI and deploys that automatically. I used to use Ansible against EC2 instances a long time ago but it doesn't scale well and is awful with ASGs.

Comment: Great tips! You just saved me from a pitfall. You divined what I was about to do, eg. `tf (generic ami) -> asg && ansible -> asg instances`. If I understand your guide properly, I should do: `tf (gen.ami) -> master.inst && ansible -> mr.inst && packer (mr.inst) -> mr.ami && tf (mr.ami) -> asg instances` to prevent scaling issues you had experienced?

Comment: Nope, just Packer + Ansible to generate the AMI and then Terraform to deploy the AMI as either an EC2 instance or, better yet, an ASG.

Comment: Understood. The first set of steps before `packer (mr.inst)` are specific to what I need in terms of "filling in" a base instance before wrapping it as ami. Then I re-read packer docs again, sure enough you're right in that I over-thunk it. I could just run packer with some generic image, provision it the way I need it and be on my way. Thanks much again! PS. I also re-read `ansible` docs again as it turns out I didn't even need to build my inventory file [dyn inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script)